# Check which UIButton was Clicked from another function

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uibutton, sender

In my xib I have taken 4 UIbuttons named button 1, 2, 3 and 4. These four buttons are connected two four different IBAction methods which perform different functions.

Now I have  one more button called "Save" This has also a different IBAction method.

```
- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender
{

}
```

Now here I want to check which of the above 4 UIButtons have been clicked.

For this I tried checking this way

```
- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender
{
   if(sender == button1)
   {
      //Do this
   }
   else if (sender == button2)
   {
       //Do this
   }

}
```

But this is not working. I am doing something wrong.Please help me out

Regards
Ranjit.

Comment: This should work, although you'd be better off using `isEqual:` instead of pointer comparison, but really I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi @H2CO3, thanks for your reply,I checked by break points and it is not working. and save IBAction method is only connected to save button.

Comment: @H2CO3 this won't work as `sender` is always his `Save` button.

Comment: @Ranjit you have to set the property of button which is pressed and then check that property in save method

Comment: @Hemang if you read his question, he has connected his save button to `Save:` method which leads to `sender` as `save button`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, I didnt get you, can you explain it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23688/discussion-between-inder-kumar-rathore-and-ranjit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tag values for each button in the interface builder and  set actions of all buttons to this method

//set global variable flag.

```
   int flag;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

switch ([sender tag])
{
    case 0:
         {
              flag =0;
             // implement action for first button

         }
        break;
    case 1:
        {
              flag =1;
            // implement action for second button

        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {
              flag =2;
            // implement action for third button

        }
        break;
        //so on
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

for save button

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{

switch (flag)
{
    case 0:
         {

             //  first button clicked

         }
        break;
    case 1:
        { 
            //  second button clicked

        }
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            //  third button clicked

        }
        break;
        //so on
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: You have not understood my question.I just want to check which of the four buttons is clicked in my save button.

Comment: multiple button clicking is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Define a class level ivar as

```
UIButton *selectedBtn;
```

Then in you IBActions

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
    selectedBtn = sender // or button1
}

- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender {
    selectedBtn = sender // or button2
}

- (IBAction)button3:(id)sender {
    selectedBtn = sender // or button3
}

- (IBAction)button4:(id)sender {
    selectedBtn = sender // or button4
}

- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender
{
    //Check output of below statement to ensure you're getting a sender
    NSLog(@"Sender: %@", sender);

   if(selectedBtn == button1)
   {
      NSLog(@"Button 1 pressed");
      //Do this
   }
   else if (selectedBtn == button2)
   {
      NSLog(@"Button 2 pressed");
       //Do this
   }
    else if (selectedBtn == button3)
   {
      NSLog(@"Button 3 pressed");
       //Do this
   }
    else if (selectedBtn == button4)
   {
      NSLog(@"Button 4 pressed");
       //Do this
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    //Check output of below statement to ensure you're getting a sender
    NSLog(@"Sender: %@", sender);

   if([pressedButton isEqual:button1])
   {
      NSLog(@"Button 1 pressed");
      //Do this
   }
   else if ([pressedButton isEqual:button2])
   {
      NSLog(@"Button 2 pressed");
       //Do this
   }

}
```

Comment: Sender will always be the save button, never 'button1', 'button2' etc as this method is the target action ONLY for the save button.

Answer (score 0):

In your save method, check the Selected property of the other 4 buttons. If you do not want to keep the buttons in a selected state, but just want to see if they were clicked at some point, then define a property (e.g. an array) to track which buttons were clicked during the session, and check this property in your save method.